# SQL Server 2008 result String replacement - multi-identifier

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, replace, for-xml

I am currently stuck with running the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    c.[DeviceName],
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'CFRM-Server%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'CFRM',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'Communication Module%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'Communication Module',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'GEBIT-Commons-Java%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'Gebit Commons Java',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'GEBIT-Commons_JBOSS%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'Gebit Commons JBOSS',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'Mobile Store%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'Mobile Store',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'NEWPOSS-Store-Server%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'NEWPOSS',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'Store Portal - Complete%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'Store Portal',
    STUFF((SELECT ' + ' +  sw.[SuiteName] FROM [dbo].[AppSoftwareSuites] as sw where sw.[Computer_Idn] = c.[Computer_Idn] AND sw.[SuiteName] like 'Store S&R Services%' FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS 'SSR'
FROM 
    [dbo].[Computer] as c WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    c.[DeviceName] LIKE '%STL01'
ORDER BY 
    c.[DeviceName] ASC;
```

Output is fine, but it seems that one product (for 'SSR') in the database has a "&" character which leads to an corrupt output ('Store S&R Services' instead of 'S&R Services xx.xx.xx').

Any chance to perform an string replacement in the output?

Reason for the 'For XML' is because of double entries per DeviceName in the Database which leads to an empty result.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this:

```
DECLARE @teststring VARCHAR(100)='This is for test & show';

SELECT(SELECT ' + ' + @teststring FOR XML PATH(''));

SELECT((SELECT ' + ' + @teststring FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'));
```

The two results are:

```
+ This is for test &amp; show
+ This is for test & show
```

Using `FOR XML` with forbidden characters (in most cases '<, > and &') will lead to *escape entities*. XML just cannot use these characters as they have meta semantics.

There are more characters which can lead to troubles like a line break or many *foreign characters*...

The easy solution: Wrap your `SELECT ... FOR XML ...` as shown in the second line and read the internal value via `value()`method. This will implicitly re-code the entities to the former characters.